# MediaController

Tags: android

Я создал `CardView` и посредством этого класса организую список из карточек, но как мне правильно создать экземпляр медиакорнтроллера? Вот сам класс:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewName;
        TextView textViewVersion;
        ImageView imageViewIcon;
        VideoView videoView;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            this.textViewVersion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewVersion);

            this.videoView = (VideoView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        }
    }

    public CustomerAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data) {
        this.dataSet = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cards_layout, parent, false);

        view.setOnClickListener(TabFragment1.myOnClickListener);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        TextView textViewName = holder.textViewName;
        TextView textViewVersion = holder.textViewVersion;

        VideoView videoView = holder.videoView;

        textViewName.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getName());
        textViewVersion.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getVersion());
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(dataSet.get(listPosition).getUrl()));
        MediaController mediaController = new
                MediaController();
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

        videoView.start();

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }
}
MediaController mediaController = new
                MediaController(this); --не правильно!
```

Comment: Так пробовали `MediaController mediaController = new
                MediaController(textViewName.getContext());`?

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что у вас неправильно?

Comment: вы случаем не вне класса объявляете и инициализируете переменную  mediaController ?

Comment: Медиаконтроллер добавил, а как еще сделать превью, а то черный экран как-то не катит.